# Does $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=-N^2}^{N^2} f(\tfrac{n}{N}) \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx $ work for integrable functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I was reading about the Fourier transform over $\mathbb{R}$, in that case, the Fourier coefficients read:
$$ \hat{g}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) e^{2\pi i x \xi} \, dx $$
Is it possible to approximate this with a Riemann sum?  What if I discretize the real line with increments of length $\frac{1}{N}$, then we need $N^2$ such intervals to cover from $[-N, N]$:
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=-N^2}^{N^2} f(\tfrac{n}{N}) \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx $$
In particular we could try to do the same thing for $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x \xi} g(x)$.
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = - N^2}^{N^2} g(\tfrac{n}{N}) e^{2\pi i \frac{n}{N}\xi} \stackrel{?}{\to} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) e^{2\pi i x \xi} \, dx = \hat{g}(\xi) $$
I would have to look up properties of the Riemann integral.   Possibly these [notes](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/37506): 
$$ \liminf_{|\Delta x| \to 0} \sum_n  f(t_n) (x_{n+1} - x_n)  < \int f(x) \, dx < \limsup_{|\Delta x| \to 0} \sum_n f(t_n)(x_{n+1} - x_n) $$
where $x_n < t_n < x_{n+1}$ for each interval $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$.

---

[what does it mean for a function to be riemann integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581728/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-riemann-integrable)

Comment: If the integral exists as a Riemann integral, then by definition yes? I'm sure I misunderstand the question.

Comment: [Riemann sum on infinite interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393943/riemann-sum-on-infinite-interval) ; [How to form the Riemann sum for an infinite interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690077/how-to-form-the-riemann-sum-for-an-infinite-interval)